# All elements point to same object

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an array of distinct objects.
However, I notice that whenever I change one object from the array, *all* elements receive that change. Obviously, I want only the object at that index to receive the change.
Here is my code:

```
//Creates the array pointer
cacheStats **directMappedTable1024Bytes = new cacheStats *[31];
//Initializes the array with cacheStats objects
    for (int i=0; i<31; i++)
{
    table[i] = new cacheStats();
}

//Test: Changing element of one object in the array
directMappedTable1024Bytes[5]->setTag(55);
cout << directMappedTable1024Bytes[22]->checkTag(); //should output 0
```

cacheStats code:

```
#include "cacheStats.h"
int tag;
int valid;
using namespace std;
cacheStats :: cacheStats (int t, int v)
{
tag = t;
valid = v;
}
cacheStats :: ~cacheStats()
{
}
void cacheStats :: setTag (int cacheTag)
{
tag = cacheTag;
}
void cacheStats:: setValidBit (int validBit)
{
valid = validBit;
}
int cacheStats :: checkValid()
{
return valid;
}
int cacheStats :: checkTag()
{
return tag;
}
```

**Results**
The cout outputs 55, when it should have outputted 0. If I change the preceding line to setTag(32) for example, it will output 32.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post the source to `cacheStats`? I'd guess you're not using member variables properly, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `tag` and `valid` are global variables, and as such are shared by all instances of the class. You need to turn them into instance variables (i.e. non-`static` data members of the class).